# Levi-Civita symbol and Hermitian conjugate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, tensor-calculus

When we take the Hermitian conjugate/dagger of an operator expression which contains a Levi-Civita symbol, do we need to transpose the Levi-Civita symbol? E.g., for the crossproduct

$$(\textbf{a}\times \textbf{b})_i~=~\epsilon_{ijk}\textbf{a}_{j}\textbf{b}_{k},$$

do we have

$$(\textbf{a}\times \textbf{b})_i^{\dagger}~=~\textbf{b}_{k}^{\dagger}\textbf{a}_{j}^{\dagger}\epsilon_{ikj}~?$$

Comment: Your notation seems off - why do the vectors $\vec a,\vec b$ have a double index? The cross product is $(\vec a\times \vec b)_i = \epsilon_{ijk}a_j b_k$.

Comment: ACuriousMind - now that I've fixed the notation (thanks again), how about the original question: should we transpose the Levi-Civita tensor when we take the dagger of the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ACuriousMind said your expression is not correct:
$$(\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b})_i = \epsilon_{ijk} a_j b_k$$
So taking the dagger:
$$(\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b})_i^{\dagger} = (\epsilon_{ijk})^\dagger a_j^\dagger b_k^\dagger\\
=\epsilon_{ijk} a_j^* b_k^*$$

because $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is real scalar, and $a_j$ and $b_k$ are complex scalars. (for scalars the transpose conjugate is just the conjugate, and for real scalars it changes nothing at all).

---

Since you objected to levi civita symbol being a scalar I will show you in another way that the symbol indeed doesn't change.

$$\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b} = \left[\begin{matrix} a_2b_3-a_3b_2 \\
-a_1b_3+a_3b_1\\
a_1b_2-a_2b_1 \end{matrix}\right] \implies 
\left[\begin{matrix}\epsilon_{123}=1 & \epsilon_{132}=-1\\
\epsilon_{213}=-1 & \epsilon_{231}=1\\
\epsilon_{312}=1 & \epsilon_{321}=-1
\end{matrix}\right]$$

which are the correct values of the Levi Civita symbol.

$$(\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b})^\dagger = \left[\begin{matrix} a_2^*b_3^*-a_3^*b_2^* &
-a_1^*b_3^*+a_3^*b_1^*&
a_1^*b_2^*-a_2^*b_1^* \end{matrix}\right] \implies 
\left[\begin{matrix}\epsilon_{123}=1 & \epsilon_{132}=-1\\
\epsilon_{213}=-1 & \epsilon_{231}=1\\
\epsilon_{312}=1 & \epsilon_{321}=-1
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Which is exactly what the first part before the line break will give you.

Comment: The Levi-Civita tensor IMHO is not a scalar, hence the question?

Comment: It isn't? It can only be $\pm 1$. Just because it has indices doesn't mean it is a tensor. Those indices are there only for the order. As far as I know the levi-civita object is invariant under coordinate transforms and hence scalar.

Comment: Yupp it doesn't transform as a tensor. Check this: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/upper-and-lower-index-levi-civita-tensor-symbol.443475/

Comment: I edited the answer, checkitout! :)

Comment: Well, an object with 3 indices i,j,k would not be a scalar. However, what is happening here IMHO is that the i,j,k indices are fixed by the implicit double summation (on j and k), so that scalar values are extracted from the otherwise triply indexes tensor...

Comment: As I pointed out earlier, you can't really call it a tensor if it doesn't transform with the coordinates can you?

Comment: If we write $(\textbf{a}\times\textbf{b})_i=\Sigma_j\Sigma_k \epsilon_{ijk} \textbf{a}_j \textbf{b}_k$, we can readily see that $j$ and $k$ are in fact not free indices, and therefore that $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is no longer the whole tensor, but scalars extracted from it... I think my confusion stemmed from the use of implicit summations.

Comment: gautam - see my next comment: there is a tensor, there is implicit double summation, and those summations fix the index, so that scalars are "extracted" from the tensor.

Comment: To continue, $(\textbf{a}\times\textbf{b})_i=\Sigma_j\Sigma_k \epsilon_{ijk} \textbf{a}_j \textbf{b}_k$ leads to: $(\textbf{a}\times\textbf{b})_i^{\dagger}=\Sigma_j\Sigma_k (\epsilon_{ijk} \textbf{a}_j \textbf{b}_k)^{\dagger}=\Sigma_j\Sigma_k \epsilon_{ijk} (\textbf{a}_j \textbf{b}_k)^{\dagger}$, the last step being unambiguous now, because $i,j,k$ are fixed, so $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is clearly a scalar.

Comment: Hmm... you are right

Comment: You are right too! :-) we are saying the same thing, but I am just at peace now since I found some reason why $\epsilon_{ijk}$ indeed is a scalar in that expression :-)

Answer (score 1):

I want to add, that the situation changes if the elements of these vectors are operators. Since this is what your notation might imply. Taking the definition of what a vector product for these quantities should mean, i.e.

$$(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})_k = \epsilon_{ijk} a_i b_j \hspace{1cm} (1)$$

then gives by definition (note that $(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger$)

$$(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})_k^\dagger = \epsilon_{ijk} b_j^\dagger a_i^\dagger = -\epsilon_{jik} b_j^\dagger a_i^\dagger=-(\mathbf{b}^\dagger\times\mathbf{a}^\dagger)_k$$

As pointed out by gautam1168, $\epsilon_{ijk}$ appears as a real scalar in the right hand side of (1). You see however that, taking the transpose conjugate of the initial statement is equivalent to perform a contraction with a certain kind of transpose of the Levi-Cita tensor with respect to the first two indices in such a way, that again a definition of a vector product is recovered. And, very important: the statement differs from yours by a minus sign (due to the anti-symmetry of $\epsilon_{ijk}$ swapping $i\leftrightarrow j$).

Answer (score 1):

Are you curious about the case where the $a_j, b_k$ are matrices or operators?

As in gautam1168's answer.

$$(\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b})_i = \epsilon_{ijk} a_j b_k$$
So taking the dagger:
$$(\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b})_i^{\dagger} = (\epsilon_{ijk})^\dagger b_k^\dagger a_j^\dagger,$$
because $(\epsilon_{ijk})^\dagger$ is just a number which commutes with whatever. For the same reason, if $a_j, b_k$ are numbers, then one can change the order of $b_k^\dagger, a_j^\dagger$ if he likes.

Comment: I was thinking about the vectors of operators - but it makes IMHO little difference to the discussion?

Comment: @Frank Generally, operators do not commute with each other but numbers do. Numbers can be treated as the special case of operators.